# JavaFX 2 - access windows system microphone volume

Tags: java, system, javafx-2, volume, microphone

There is any way to access and manipulate the system microphone volume as if i were on the Windows sound manager?
With a slider i should set my favorite mic volume and visualize the current selected volume. Of course i'm on a stand alone application and not on a web based one.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues related to this in JFX jira : javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-3458 and javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-22200. According to them, it is not supported now, and I think, it will not be supported in 8.0.

You can pay an attention to the JDK sound API:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/sound/programmer_guide/chapter6.html

Especially this fragment :

> Changing a Line's Volume Let's assume your program associates a
>   particular graphic slider with a particular line's volume control. The
>   value of a volume control (i.e., FloatControl.Type.VOLUME) is set
>   using the following FloatControl method:
>
> void setValue(float newValue) Detecting that the user moved the
>   slider, the program gets the slider's current value and passes it, as
>   the parameter newValue, to the method above. This changes the volume
>   of the signal flowing though the line that "owns" the control.

On the stackoverflow question about capturing microphone:

[Java Sound API - capturing microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705581/java-sound-api-capturing-microphone)