# How do you get a TargetDataLine from a Mixer Info (Java Sound API)?

Tags: java

First off, I am not experienced at all with the Sound API and am looking for some quick advice.  I have a mixer object and a `TargetDataLine` that I want to use to record using the mixer.  Here is what I have gotten:

```
final TargetDataLine line;
try {
    line = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(mixer.getLineInfo());
} catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, this code passes an `IllegalArgumentException` when executed.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-14" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: interface Mixer
at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice.getLine(Unknown Source)
at net.minecraft.src.SequenceAudioHandler.run(SequenceAudioHandler.java:32)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?  Sorry if I am lacking basic knowledge, I'm still trying to learn.

Comment: Can we see how you create the mixer object?

Comment: I have an ArrayList that stores certain mixers, and then passes a certain index of this ArrayList to the section above.

Can someone tell me how to post formatted code in comments?

Comment: You can simply edit your post above with the new code. You cannot format comments (to my knowledge) 'test'

Comment: @arynaq you can format comments: `test` using the ` character (the one on the same key as ~)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your || in the tests. Even if the line is not supported but has a certain name you accept it as a viable mixer. So when you try and get a line from it later on you get a `IllegalArgumentException` - "*if this mixer does not support any lines matching the description"*
per the documentation.

If what you are trying to do is get a line that can record audio from your microphone I suggest this question/answer:
[Java Sound API - capturing microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705581/java-sound-api-capturing-microphone)

Comment: I had an OR statement in the iteration through the mixers, that allowed Stereo Mix to be included.  I got rid of it and had the same result.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the added code of Mixer creation?