# Create Stream of audio (microphone) and video (desktop) in Java

Tags: java, stream, streaming, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I need create an application desktop in Java that can read the desktop and microphone and create a stream of audio/video to export in rtmp or other format.

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: I want create a video conference in java :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this for capturing the Screen:

```
Robot r = null;

    try {
        r = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedImage img = r.createScreenCapture(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds());
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705581/java-sound-api-capturing-microphone) will help you to record the audio.