# How do you mute a microphone using Java?

Tags: java, windows, hardware, microphone

I have looked around and tried the following in-built library:

```
javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem
```

to get microphone information / mute microphone(s) / unmute, but this deals more with streaming files. I also found the following in relation to microphone access with Java, but that's streaming audio from the microphone: [Java Sound API - capturing microphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705581/java-sound-api-capturing-microphone)

How do I, using the aforementioned library or similar to that in the question linked, mute / unmute one or more microphones in Windows via Java?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Ok - can you recommend a website that would be useful for helping me with this Java programming query?

Comment: No, because that is still off-topic.

Comment: I've read through your link, and I will edit the question into a HOW question instead of a WHAT question, because phrasing in order to ask the same question might get me past this red tape.